# python parse excel, how to convert long to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

excel a cell value is `42001640842052500000`, and using python to parse this value, it auto becoming `4.20016408420525e+19`, and how to resolve this problem? 
how to convert the cell value `42001640842052500000` to string?

Answer (score 0):

Python typically thinks of such a large number as a float, you can just use str(variable_name) to convert variable_name to string.

```
var=1e-6
string_var = str(var)
```

Also, I think it would be a good idea to check if it's stored as a string in excel as well, to remove any inconsistencies